# Make image high contrast - 2 tone black and white

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion, black

Ive got a bunch of logos i want to display on a 'press' page, the logos all have different color schemes, which clash so i want to make all the logos black and white, no greyscale, just 2 colours, black and white.

Ive tried in Photoshop to set the color pallet to greyscale and then up the contrast, but i still get allot of greys in the logos, any idea hows best to achieve this.

Id like to do something similar to this example were the logo is completely flattened, see there is no tonal effect on the letters as there is on the color version.

Just to be clear all the logos, are raster, rather than vector so they cant just be put into illustrator and changed.

[image: Google colour logo]
[image: Google Black]

Comment: Desaturate the image (to turn into grayscale) then use the levels tool to push it into the black.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a Hue/Saturation adjustment layer and turn the saturation down to zero. You can then turn the lightness down as needed to make it black.

Edit: Sorry I assumed you had a transparent background. Instead, use the threshhold adjustment layer. It will turn your image pure black/white

Comment: Thanks but i couldnt get this to work just seemed to end up with a dark grey, greyscaled image - http://imgur.com/L0urRiP - any ideas ?

Comment: @sam Updated answer

Comment: How can you then get rid of the white background? When applying my color overlay, it is applying to the white background as well.

Comment: There are several techniques, but here is a good/quick way especially because you're using black and white. Select all ctrl+a of your b/w logo image and copy ctrl+c. Create a layer mask and alt+click on your layer mask icon in the layers panel. This will put you in the layer mask special editing mode (not sure it's official name) - now paste in place sft+ctrl+v. Invert it (flipping the colors) with ctrl+i and exit the layer mask edit mode. Let me know how you go...

Comment: Here is another answer that gives a step by step on the technique mentioned in my comment above: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21685/replacing-whiteness-with-transparency-in-cs6/21686#21686

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Blending Modes > Color Overlay on all the layers so you can make the logos any color you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The Threshold Tool might be really helpful on this project. Then using Color overlay to pick a specific color. I realize that this thread happened about a year ago, but I thought I would post this just in case somebody else comes looking (like I did).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try converting the logo like you are converting a colour photograph to black and white?

Try Layers > Add adjustment layer > Channel Mixer and check on the "monochrome" option.

After that you just use the sliders to adjust the highlights and tones.

You can even add another adjustment layer >  curves and change the tone of the image. I hope this helps and I used this method to convert colour images to black and white.