# how to make a color transparent in GIMP

Tags: gimp, transparency

I realize there are a ton of questions like this, but they are all way overcomplicated for what I am trying to do.

What I want to do is very simple.  I want the background of my image completely transparent, and the foreground completely opaque.  My background is white while my foreground is a pale blue and gold.  Whenever I use `color to alpha` I end up with the foreground being semi-transparent.

How do I make the background transparent without changing the transparency of the foreground?

Comment: it is better to repace this way: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/21685 .

Comment: @qdinar Why is it better? What you link is Photoshop and not GIMP, GIMP's Color to Alpha works perfectly.

Comment: @CsabaToth maybe i had a case with white areas in the foreground which i wanted not to make transparent, but i wanted transparency in the border, to not have white borders when selection is pasted onto other background.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Whenever we choose to change a color to transparent with the *Layer > Transparency> Color to alpha* tool we will also introduce semi-transparency of colors different to the selected. Below this is shown for making white in the background transparent:

[image]

In case this is not wanted we need to select only a single colored area for transparency. This can be done with the [*Select By Color* tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-by-color-select.html) (*Tools* → *Selection Tools* → *By Color Select*) [image] [image].

- Make the threshold of selection low to zero to select only a single color.
- Feather the selection for a smoother transition.
- Add a transparent layer if not yet present (*Layers > Transparency > Add Alpha Channel*)
- Clear (*Edit > Clear* or <kbd>Del</kbd>) the selected color to make it transparent:

[image]

Comment: I coudn't realize how to "Make the threshold of selection low"

Comment: @ShirleyTemple it is what the tools option for Gimp "select by color" lets you choose. The higher the threshold the more similar colors are included.

Comment: That still leaves a white halo around, instead of replacing the white with transparency.

Comment: @Flimm you may have to feather the selection a bit more to get rid of any anti-aliasing white that may still be there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Select by Color Tool". Not the "Color Picker Tool". Be sure to Layer-Transparency-Add Alpha Channel. Try a higher threshold setting like 29 instead of 0 of the "Select by Color Tool". Then Press Delete. No Halo :)