# Changing image color

Tags: gimp, transparency, color-conversion

I am by no means a Graphic Designer but try. I have an [image](http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/banzaitokyo/medico/64/surgeon-icon.png) I got from [iconarchive](http://www.iconarchive.com/show/medico-icons-by-banzaitokyo/surgeon-icon.html) and am trying to set the color to red (#840a0c) and setting transparent where there is white. I am using GIMP for this task and every time I give it a whirl I get jagged edges and it just looks awful:

Original icon:

[image]

Modified icon:

[image]

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: It would be easier for you if you downloaded Inkscape and used it to build the entire image as a vector instead of the process you're trying, but that's just me.

Comment: Downloaded Inkscape and am completely lost.

Comment: Ideally these would be vector icons to begin with--which would make creating color and transparency very easy in Inkscape. Alas, these are PNG files, which isn't doing you any favors. You'll need to use a process like this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21685/replacing-whiteness-with-transparency-in-cs6/21686#21686

Comment: Note that in the end, it's likely less painful to just by a set of vector icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in such an icon is the antialiasing zone between the black and the white.

@ybeltukov approach with **GIMP** is correct. In order to proceed and clear the white zone you need to select it (by color or with the magic wand) and tweak a little e.g. increasing the selection by 1 pixel and [feather](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-selection-feather.html) the selection to avoid the pixeling effect visible in your example.

In **Inkscape** is not so difficult.

At first you need to import the icon, while dragging it or using File->Import... (you can either embed or link the icon, for this example it doesn't matter).

[image: icon embedded in Inkscape]

Next step is vectorize the image, i.e. convert the pixels of the image in vertex and lines. This task could be performed using Path -> Trace Bitmap... (the icon must be selected). It appears a window with the settings:

[image: Trace bitmap]

You need to find the optimal settings for your image. With "Update" button you can have a preview.

When done, hit "Ok" button and close the window. The traced image is over the original one, as a group of paths.

[image: traced image]

Now, you can ungroup the image, choose the paths more close to your icon, edit a bit them (refer to a [manual](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/)) and change the colors as you need:

[image: final step]

Now, you can export the image (File -> Export Bitmap...) as a png (note that the inner of the image is transparent, now):

[image: final icon]

So... using **GIMP or Inkscape**? Depends of your needs.

Comment: Played a bit per your instructions and got it. Thanks!

Comment: @Rick Very well! If you want, you can mark as answered the question, now.

Comment: `Now, you can ungroup the image, choose the paths more close to your icon, edit a bit them (refer to a manual) and change the colors as you need:` — I apologize, you could give more full reference? I don't understand how to make it. Thanks.

Comment: When you [trace](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Trace.html) a bitmap, you can choose how many *Scans* will be generated. As result of the trace you get a group of paths (one path for each scan), and you can work and edit (or remove) each path in order to obtain a more suitable image. I suggest you to **try** with simple bitmaps and to **read** manuals, tutorials and references.

Answer (score 2):

Dead simple! Just put a layer above the logo layer with the colour (or texture) you want to apply to the logo layer below and set the opacity mode to <kbd>screen</kbd> and the edges will look nice and clean too.

I second what the other guys are saying about leaning Inkscape however!

EDIT:
I just noticed that your original logo is dark grey rather than black so this method will give a lighter shade than the screen layer. You need to adjust the levels of this logo layer so that the black is fully black. I know the following screenshot is Photoshop but Gimp has a levels tool under  <kbd>Colours > Levels</kbd>  too and it's practically the same thing. Again, this is much better to do in a vector program.

[image]

Comment: Does this work only for black original images?

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak color curves to obtain a smooth picture. Just increase the red component and decrease green and blue components:

[image]

It is simple, but it is difficult to obtain the specified color exactly (#840a0c) as in @marcusdoesstuff's solution.

Another (less accurate) possibility is to select only RGB channels (not alpha) and apply filling with the proper threshold

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a rather convoluted method of changing a black and white logo to colour. Colour curves is better suited to tweaking photography (eg. for imitating cross-process film development).

Comment: @marcusdoesstuff All methods are possible if they produce a correct result and require few clicks. P.S. It is not conventional to downvote on SE if you find a better solution and the previous one also works.

Comment: I actually decided that it was unfair but it won't let me change it unless the answer is edited. This is, however, a bit like using a knife to eat soup. When you want to change a colour to a specific shade or hex curves just isn't the tool that's designed for the job.

Comment: @marcusdoesstuff, I edited my post and add the mention of your post with the same idea! :)

Comment: fixed for you :)